# Save the order of the tabs in TabBarC (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

How to save the order of the tabs of the TabBarController if the user is changing the order in the menu of the tabs:[image]

Without adding code the app is not saving the order and is taking the default one, from Xcode.
Should I use a TabBarController Class?
Thanks!

Comment: What class are you currently using? Did you try embedding your ViewController in a TabBarController already? Do you have 5 different VC attached to the root VC that controls the tabs? It depends on the flow of how your root VC works.

Comment: There are more then 6 Classes/VC´s. All are simple UIViewController with a Navigation Controller.

Comment: Did you add a relationship-segue for each to the rootViewController?

Comment: Every ViewController has one segue to respectively one Navigation Controller

Comment: Each VC needs to be set to the root UITabController.

Comment: They do what? They are or they aren't?

Comment: Each VC has got respectively one NavigationController. All Navigation Controllers are connected to the TabBarController

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95253/discussion-between-lukesivi-and-developer-he).